# How to access value of a dynamically created text node in a later click event?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript project. It's a multiplication table that when click on each cell it should be show the result of that cell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>
    .tdstyles {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Holder"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var m;
window.onload = function () {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.border = 1;
    table.cellPadding = 0;
    table.cellSpacing = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');

        for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            m = i*j;
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var newContent = document.createTextNode(m);
            td.className = "tdstyles";
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.appendChild(newContent);
            document.getElementsByTagName("td").innerHTML = m;
            td.onclick = function () {
               console.log();
            };
            var a = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
            var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
            var c = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
            td.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ")";

            // myFunction();
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
        Holder.appendChild(table)
    }
  };
</script>
```

How can I save that TextNode when it is in loop and use it when click on that td?

Comment: Inside the click handler, use `console.log(this.innerText);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the reference to the text in a closure for each inner iteration so that it can be accessed later. Also note that it's probably a lot easier to assign to the `textContent` of an element if its only child is going to be a text node.

```
for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
  const text = i * j;
  const td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  td.textContent = 'text';
  td.className = "tdstyles";
  td.onclick = function() {
    console.log(text);
  };
  // ...
```

Do note that I'm using `const` and `let` rather than `var` - this is very important. `var` has function scope and is hoisted, which can easily result in confusion, especially when you have any asynchronous code; `const` and `let` are much more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the JavaScript in older browsers, you can wrap the onclick with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and send the text as an argument.

```
 for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
     var text = i * j;
     var td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
     td.textContent = 'text';
     td.className = "tdstyles";
     !function (t) {
         td.onclick = function() {
             console.log(t);
         }
     }(text);
     ///...
 }
```